# Árvore binária de busca

Tags: c, ponteiro, árvore-binária, ciência-da-computação

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


struct arvore
{
    int key;
    struct arvore * right, *left;


};

typedef struct arvore Arvore;   

Arvore * alocar(int key)
{
    Arvore * p = (Arvore *)malloc(sizeof(Arvore));
    p->key = key;
    p->right = NULL;
    p->left = NULL;
    return p;

}

int procurafolha(Arvore * p)
{
    int a = 0;
    if(p->right == NULL && p->left == NULL)
    {
        return p->key;
    }
    else
    { 
        if(p->left != NULL)
        {   
            a = a + procurafolha(p->left);
        }
        if(p->right != NULL)
        {
            a = a + procurafolha(p->right);
        }
    }   

    return a;

}

int procurasemfolha(Arvore * p)
{
    int a = 0;

    if(p->left != NULL)
    {
        a = a + procurasemfolha(p->left);
    }
    if(p->right != NULL)
    {
        a = a + procurasemfolha(p->right);
    }
    if(p->right != NULL || p->left != NULL)
    {
        a = a + p->key;

    }

    return a;

}




Arvore * insere(Arvore * p, int key)
{

    if(p == NULL)
    {
        p = alocar(key);
        return p;

    }
    else if(key < p->key)
    {
        p->left = insere(p->left, key);
    }   
    else if(key > p->key)
    {
        p->right = insere(p->right, key);
    }



}

void libera(Arvore * p)
{
    if(p != NULL)
    {
        libera(p->left);
        libera(p->right);
        free(p);
        p = NULL;
    }   


}


int main()
{

    Arvore *p = NULL;
    char a;
    int n, i = 0;
    int qtd, qtd01;

    while(1)
    {
        scanf("%d", &n);
        p = insere(p, n);
        scanf("%c", &a);
        if(a == '\n')
        {
            break;
        }

    }

    qtd = procurafolha(p);
    qtd01 = procurasemfolha(p);

    printf("%d %d\n", qtd, qtd01);

    libera(p);





return 0;   
}
```

Explicação do problema:
Você deverá imprimir dois valores inteiros separados por espaço, o primeiro com a soma dos elementos que são folhas, o segundo com a soma dos elementos internos (não são folhas).

**Teste 1:**

> entrada
>
> ```
> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
> ```
>
> saida
>
> ```
> 10 45
> ```

**Teste 2:**

> entrada
>
> ```
> 5 3 7 2 4 6 8
> ```
>
> saida
>
> ```
> 20 15
> ```

**Teste 3:**

> entrada
>
> ```
> 10 2 3 0 5 1 15 20 4 6 7 8 11 9 12 16 19 17 18 21
> ```
>
> saida
>
> ```
> 65 139
> ```

Answer (score 0):

A sua função `insere` tem o retorno em falta, o que não lhe permite construir corretamente a arvore. O valor a retornar tem que ser `p`:

```
Arvore * insere(Arvore * p, int key){
    ...

    return p; //falta este retorno
}
```

E isto já irá fazer com que as suas funções respondam ao problema.

[Veja como obtêm o resultado correto no Ideone](https://ideone.com/x9BpU5)

No entanto pode simplificar consideravelmente a lógica das funções para achar as somas. Segue a minha sugestão para ambas:

```
int soma_folhas(Arvore *p){
    if (p == NULL) return 0;

    int valorNo = (p->left == NULL && p->right == NULL) ? p->key : 0;
    return valorNo + soma_folhas(p->left) + soma_folhas(p->right);
}

int soma_nao_folhas(Arvore *p){
    if (p == NULL) return 0;

    int valorNo = (p->left == NULL && p->right == NULL) ? 0 : p->key;
    return valorNo + soma_nao_folhas(p->left) + soma_nao_folhas(p->right);
}
```

[Exemplo desta versão também no Ideone](https://ideone.com/yjloUB)

Saliento que apenas o `valorNo` mudou entre ambas as funções, pois uma folha é o inverso de não folha. Logo apenas o valor de verdeiro e falso do operador ternário foi trocado.

Repare que também troquei o nome das funções para que fossem mais intuitivos e percetíveis relativo ao que fazem realmente.